# Команды недоступны в терминале phpStorm, но работают в обычном терминале Windows

Tags: php, консоль, cmd, phpstorm, composer

Открываю папку в терминале windows и в phpstorm
Пытаюсь обновить композер, но шторм не видит команду. Причем такое поведение только с командой composer. Не пойму как исправить? Подскажите, пожалуйста.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: там консолька мб открывается от другого юзера. Посмотрите в настройках системы, путь к композеру у вас прописан в `%PATH%` для юзера или системный.

Comment: путь прописан и там и там в PATH

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

оказывается было пусто в наcтройке терминала, выбрал cmd и всё заработало

Settings -> tools -> terminal